# How can I get SendBird server API working?

Tags: rest, api, sdk, chat, sendbird

I am trying to get a list of channels in SendBird chat api.

`curl -d "auth=API_TOKEN" https://api.sendbird.com/channel/list`

It keeps returning `Invalid Params`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `json/application` content type and body should be `json`.

For example:

```
curl -d '{"auth":"API_TOKEN"}' -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST https://api.sendbird.com/channel/list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try To pass Api-Token with Header 

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();            
                request.Headers.Add("Api-Token", SendBirdApiToken);
                request.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(SendBirdUserUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                var result = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, CancellationToken.None);
```

**SendBirdApiToken** is your App Api-Token on SendBird Portal